# What are the available geometries of magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Is it possible to have a magnetic field of a any geometry we want, or there are only few types of geometries that can be achieved with permanent magnets and electromagnets? If the former, how do we produce a magnetic field of specific geometry? For example, can the magnetic field be cylindrical or can it be swirl? If the latter, can I see what are the available geometries of all the possible magnetic fields?

Comment: Do you mean theoretically or in practice?

Comment: Not theoretically, but in practice